# Adding a GIF into Experience Builder

Tags: time-series, animation, arcgis-experience-builder

I've created a time series animation in ArcGIS Pro and exported it into a GIF. Is it possible to add the time series GIF into Experience Builder and play automatically when I am on that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the image widget in the ArcGIS Online Experience Builder.

You can use this widget to add the following image formats: `PNG, GIF, JPG, JPEG, and BMP.`

Simply:

[image]

For more information follow the documentation:

https://doc.arcgis.com/en/experience-builder/configure-widgets/image-widget.htm